# Why does a Certificate Authority (CA) issue certificates from an intermediate authority instead of the root authority?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ca

When a digital certificate is purchased it is verified by recursively following the chain of "issued by" authorities which ends at the certificate of the root CA.

An inspection of a few of the web sites of companies selling certificates shows that their certificates are actually issued by an intermediate CA for the same company. The leaf certificate and the (freely downloadable) intermediate certificate must both be installed on the web server for it to work.

Various documents explain how this setup works where the intermediate CA is a different company from the root CA. But here they are for the same company.

Does anyone know some key reason(s) that a CA would issue certificates from an intermediate CA rather than its own root CA? I presume there are various administrative scenarios that are helped by this situation (e.g. intermediate certificate can be set to expire before root certificate) but to some extent I'm guessing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons to do that.

1. Root CA is the top CA in the trust hierarchy. Current PKI (standartized by RFC5280) doesn't provide any means to revoke root CA certificate. Therefore root CA compromise (which is more likely if root CA acts as issuing CA) is a very serious problem.
2. Based on 1st paragraph, root CA is very sensitive and it (at least should) requires a high level of security with very limited access. It is not possible to follow high security with high-load request flow.
3. Since root CA provides a common trust anchor for an organization and each company may need defferent levels of assurance and security, you will need to have a lot of root CAs, one per need.

It is already said that root CA maintenance over platforms (Windows, *nix, Linux, Mac) is not that simple, it is reasonable to set up a single root CA and set up several intermediate CAs under the single root. In this case, each intermediate CA will be restricted by specific usages (say, one for SSL certificates, one for code signing certificates, one for e-mail, etc.) and policy.

In this scenario if something went wrong with issuing CA (which is intermediate), CA owner may revoke compromised intermediate CA without having to go through long and complex process of root CA removal from clients.

Also, intermediate CAs are relatively changed to reflect most modern PKI trends. With single root CA it is easier to implement a new intermediate CA without having to go through long and complex process of adding root CA to clients.

To summarize the reasons: higher security and better manageability.

Comment: Thanks for these comments: exactly what I was hoping for and helped me make a few extra connections between things I'd not previously thought about. I didn't know about the lack of a means to revoke root CA, but I suppose thinking it through the Certificate Revocation List applies to the certificates at the next level *down* so a different mechanism would be needed for something at the same (top) level.

Comment: Yes. RFC doesn't define such mechanisms (even don't give any idea) and they specially note about sensivity of root CA.

Comment: Point 1 is what I don't understand - if every chain ends in the root CA anyway, why are root CAs less likely to be compromised than intermediate CAs? How does adding an extra step in the chain improve security?

Comment: Because extremely limited set of personnel and applications can access root CA. Often it requires a whole and complex ceremony. You can't provide a high volume of issued certificates in this scenario. It is not about cryptographic security, it is about operational practices.